# R bar-chart with Multiple Columns on X-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

| year | implicit | explicit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | 37 |
| 2020 | 13 | 19 |
| 2019 | 10 | 43 |
| 2018 | 15 | 28 |
| 2017 | 4 | 21 |

I am learning R and have been struggling with creating bar charts in ggplot. With the above table, I'd like to create a bar chart that has year on the x axis and has two columns each year (one for implicit and one for explicit). I've looked at several threads and have been unable to figure out how to organize the data to get the bar graph I want.

Comment: Welcome. df = your data frame. Try `library(tidyverse`; `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = 2:3) %>% ggplot(aes(year, value, fill = name)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")`

Comment: the idea of this is to shape your data long, and then dodge by group.